# What is the rationale behind returning unique addresses for allocations of zero size in C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, standards, new-operator

What is the rationale behind returning unique addresses for allocations of zero size in C++?

Background: the C11 standard says about malloc (7.20.3 Memory management functions):

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

That is, as I see it, `malloc` always succeeds for allocations of zero size since the only you can do with the pointer of a zero-sized allocation is call some other memory allocation function like `free` with it:

- if `malloc` returns `NULL`, `free(NULL)` is ok so this can be considered a success,
- if it returns some other value, that's also a success (because it isn't `NULL`), the only condition is that `free` on the value should also work.

Also, C11 (also 7.20.3) does not specify that the address returned from malloc must be unique, only that they must point to disjoint memory regions:

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated). The lifetime of an allocated object extends
>   from the allocation until the deallocation. Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an object disjoint from any other object.

All objects of zero size are disjoint AFAICT, and that would mean that `malloc` can return the same pointer for multiple zero-sized allocations (e.g. `NULL` would be fine), or different pointers each time, or the same pointer for some, etc.

Then C++98 came along with two raw memory allocation functions:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size);
void* operator new(std::size_t size, std::align_val_t alignment);
```

Note that these functions only return raw memory: they do not create or initialize any objects of any type AFAICT.

You call them like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
int main() {
    void* ptr = operator new(std::size_t{0});
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
    operator delete(ptr, std::size_t{0});
    return 0;
}
```

The `[new.delete.single]` section of the C++17 standard explains them, but the key guarantee as I see it is given in `[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]`:

> Even if the size of the space requested is zero, the request can fail. If the request succeeds, the value returned shall be a non-null pointer value (7.11) p0 different from any previously returned value p1, unless that value p1 was subsequently passed to an operator delete. Furthermore, for the library allocation functions in 21.6.2.1 and 21.6.2.2, p0 shall represent the address of a block of storage disjoint from the storage for any other object accessible to the caller. The effect of indirecting through a pointer returned as a request for zero size is undefined.38

That is, they must always return distinct pointers on success. That's a bit change from `malloc`.

My question is: **What is the rationale behind this change?** (that is, behind returning unique addresses for allocations of zero size in C++)

Ideally the answer would be just a link to the paper (or some other source) that explored the alternatives and motivated their semantics. Typically I go for The Design and Evolution of C++ for these C++98 questions, but Section 10 (Memory Management) does not mention anything about it. Otherwise, some sort of authoritative reference would be nice.

---

Disclaimer: I [asked it on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/8n79wj/were_zerosized_memory_allocations_a_good_idea_in/) but I did not ask nicely enough so I did not got any useful answer. I would like to kindly ask you that if you only have an hypothesis, please feel free to post it as an answer but mention that it is only an hypothesis.

Also, on reddit people went on and on about zero-sized types, whether I have a proposal to change the standard, etc. This question is about the semantics of the raw memory allocation functions when passed a size equal to zero. If topics like zero-sized types are relevant for your answer, please include them! But try not to get too derailed with tangential issues.

Also, on reddit people also threw arguments like "that's for optimization purposes" without really being able to mention anything more concrete. I'd expect something more concrete than "because optimizations" in an answer. For example, one redditor mentioned aliasing optimizations, but I wondered which kind of aliasing optimizations apply to pointers that cannot be dereferenced, and wasn't able to get anyone to comment on that. So maybe if you are going to mention optimizations, a small example that shows it would enrich the discussion.

Comment: I am going to guess [pointer provenance](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/991384169895755776) a lot of the details are going to be in WG14 defect reports though :-(

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour the link to the tweet is broken :( Is there a link to that defect report somewhere?

Comment: Fixed the link, sorry

Comment: I would expect `behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value` to imply non-null addresses returned are unique.

Comment: It goes way back into pre-standard history, and just seems like [the way it has always been](https://wg21.link/LWG9).

Comment: @John I've just added the relevant part of the C standard for that to the answer. The caveat is that the C standard does not require the non-null addresses to be unique; it requires the memory allocations to be disjoint.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks! That's maybe as close as I am going to get for a definitive answer. I still wonder why that was specifically prohibited by ARM 5.3.3. :/

Comment: @BoPersson why isn't it an answer?

Comment: But [the footnote says it is to be compatible w/ malloc/calloc](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#footnote-36) so I think disjoint means unique or at leas that is the interpretation.

Comment: @SergeyA The defect report contains no rationale beyond "ARM 5.3.3 forbid this" (no reason mentioned). It's a really good hint, but I don't know if it alone can be considered an answer. It might maybe be the best answer there ever is though :/

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That's not what the C standard says though, and if the intent was to be compatible with C the C++ standard would have kept the semantics. The [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/new.cpp#L71)  and [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/da8dff89fa9398f04b107e388cb706517ced9505/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_opa.cc#L95) implementation of the two new operators mentioned transform zero into a 1byte sized allocation making them disjoint. That is, clang and gcc don't assume in practice that malloc behaves that way.

Comment: I'd argue that the implementation-defined aspect of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` is something of a defect.  It means that a `NULL` response can actually signal _success_ if 0 bytes were requested, hence the check for success has to look something like `if ((size == 0) || (returnedPointer != NULL)) ...` and functions accepting that pointer as an argument may not realize that `NULL` may actually be "valid."  I'm not too surprised that C++98 chose to remove this issue, and of course it wasn't always the case that `operator new` threw an exception when allocation failed.

Comment: "It means that a NULL response can actually signal success if 0 bytes were requested" But does it? It might also mean "failed to allocate zero bytes". In any case, you can't dereference the returned pointer, and if one is checking for `size == 0`, why is one still calling `malloc(0)` then?

Comment: One could check for `size == 0` before calling `malloc`, of course.  The point is that that check must happen _somewhere_.  If we knew that successful `malloc` would always return a non-`NULL` pointer, then we could just check `if (returnedPointer != NULL)` after calling `malloc` -- a check that we'd have to do in any case -- and never have to worry about the `size == 0` special case.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen I can imagine an implementation of `malloc` where it does something like `if(available(p) >= size) return p;`, the check for `size == 0` need not be explicit

Comment: @PasserBy, what is `available` and where is `p` coming from?
More concretely, I can imagine:
a) Wanting `malloc` to return a new non-`NULL` pointer on 0-byte allocations.
b) Being OK with `malloc` returning `NULL` on 0-byte allocations.
If the library provides (a), then I can wrap it with a check to get (b).  If the library provides (b), then I can't construct (a) out of that.  One could -- and probably would -- argue that there's no reason to force that strengthened contract on programs that don't need it, but it does make life simpler in ways that can't really be simulated otherwise.

Comment: @PasserBy, I'd be much happier with the current situation if I could determine the 0-size allocation behavior of `malloc` at compile-time by testing a predefined macro.  As it is, we have [this warning](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM04-C.+Beware+of+zero-length+allocations).

Comment: @JoshuaGreen that's because there has been enough research about zero-allocation vulnerabilities, mostly by microsoft security engineering center, that have shown how to exploit these in some cases.

Comment: @gnzlbg, I agree with the warning, as this forces people to think about what they're doing.  I think specifying the behavior and/or allowing programmers to determine the behavior would help.  The claim "In cases where the memory allocation functions return a non-null pointer, reading from or writing to the allocated memory area results in undefined behavior" strikes me as trying to make this case seem worse than it is.  After all, reading from or writing outside of the allocated area is _always_ undefined, so this statement is just a specific case that follows from the allocated area being 0.

Comment: To continue that thought, the first "Noncompliant Code Example" is hardly fair.  For an "arbitrary" `size`, what sort of `/* Continue processing list */` code would make sense, and what would it try to do in the `size == 0` case if the author weren't specifically thinking about it?

Comment: (Hallvard Furuseth's comment at that page is along these lines.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that **objects** (no matter their size) in C++ **must have a unique identity**. So different coexisting objects (no matter their size) must have different address, since **two pointer that compare as equal are assumed to point to a same object**.

If you admit that zero-sized objects can have same address you cannot anymore distinguish if two address are or not a same object.

---

Many comments about the "new does not return objects" issue.

Please FORGET OOP terminology in this context:

C++ specification have a precise definition of what the word "Object" means.

[CPP Reference:Object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)

In particular:

> C++ programs create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects.
>   An object, in C++, is a region of storage that has
>
> - size (can be determined with sizeof);
> - alignment requirement (can be determined with alignof);
> - storage duration (automatic, static, dynamic, thread-local);
> - lifetime (bounded by storage duration or temporary);
> - type;
> - value (which may be indeterminate, e.g. for default-initialized non-class types);
> - optionally, a name.
>
> The following entities are not objects: value, reference, function,
>   enumerator, type, non-static class member, bit-field, template, class or
>   function template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, and this.
>
> A variable is an object or a reference that is not a non-static data member,
>   that is introduced by a declaration.
>
> Objects are created by definitions, new-expressions, throw-expressions, when
>   changing the active member of a union, and where temporary objects are
>   required.

Comment: But one could argue that they are the same object.

Comment: The overloads of `operator new` mentioned in the question only return raw memory: they have nothing to do with objects AFAICT.

Comment: ^That. Aliasing is a non-issue, memory returned by `operator new` is not an object. By the time an object is created, it may either be the only object there, or it destroyed a previous object by reusing its memory.

Comment: IMHO, rather than requiring that objects have a unique identity, the Standard should instead have said that an object of size N occupies N+1 addresses, the first N of which each identify a different byte owned by the object and the last N of which each immediately follow those same bytes in the same order.  Requiring that compilers pretend that empty objects take up a byte adds complexity to the language without serving a useful purpose.  Any code that wants to ensure an object's address will be unique could simply make sure its size isn't zero.

Comment: When are zero sized objects not subobjects of classes of size at least one?

Comment: @Emilio Is `void* operator new(size_t)` a `new-expression` (cppreference only says that's a function called by some of them)? What's the type of the created region of storage?

Comment: @gnzlbg A new expression is `new A` returning `A*`. It results in a call to to operator new (sizeof(A)) and a subsequent call to the A constructor.  if you call `new A` twice, you need two distinct A*, hence `opeator new` must return two distinct `void*`. Even if the size is 0.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia The thing is I am not asking about `new-expression`s in my question, but about the explicit `operator new` function calls that allocate raw memory and are used like this:   `void* ptr = operator new(size);`. AFAICT that's just a normal function call and not a `new-expression` (no types involved). If these are `new-expression`s it would be nice to add a source to your answer, because otherwise nothing in it applies to the question.

Comment: @gnzlbg: the point is that `operator new` must return memory that is suitable for object construction. So it must never be twice the same address (without an `operator delete`)

Comment: That argument makes sense. I think the unique address argument does not apply everywhere now that `[[no_unique_address]]` has been merged into the `std` (two zero-sized objects can share the same address). However, this attribute cannot be used in any places where operator new could actually return the same address for two zero-sized objects, so it does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply that code should not require special handling of boundary conditions. Many, I would say most, algorithms have to deal with zero-sized objects as boundary conditions. Less common is the algorithm that compare pointers to objects to see if they are the same object, but this still should work even for zero-sized objects.

However, your question assumes that this is a change. Apart from a brief hiatus in the late 1980's all C and C++ implementations that I am aware of have always behaved like this.

The original C compiler by dmr behaved like this but then around 1987 the draft C standard specified that malloc of a zero sized object return NULL. This was truly bizarre and even the final C-89 standard made it implementation-defined but I have never since encountered an implementation that did this horrible thing.

I talk more about this in [my blog](http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2011/11/zero.html) in the section "Malloc Madness".

Comment: Thanks for the link, will check it out :)

Comment: Note that in C++20 you can't use two pointers to see if they are the same object, because zero-sized data members are allowed to share their address with other objects (`[[no_unique_address]]`), so that will only work sometimes, at best.

Comment: If a programmer doesn't care whether the address of a zero-sized object compares equal to anything or not, then user-code handling of boundary conditions could be minimized by guaranteeing that if `p` and `q` is a valid pointer or the return of `malloc(0)`, then `p+0` and `p-0` will be equivalent to `p`, `p-p` will be equivalent to 0, `p>p`, `p<p`, and `p!=p` will all yield zero, `p>=p`, `p==p,` and `p<=p` will all yield 1, `memcpy(p,q,0) and `memmove(p,q,0)` will yield `p`, `p==q` and `p!=q` will yield 0 or 1, etc. all without side-effects.  IMHO, malloc(0) should be allowed to...

Comment: ...return a null pointer only on those systems which would uphold all of the above guarantees *anyway*.  Outside a few cases where one wants to generate a unique token (which could be better served with a proper "unique token" type) I'm not sure why code should care about whether a pointer to a "zero-sized object" compares equal or unequal to anything else.